# MacTex 2022 issues

Tags: mactex

I have two MacBookAirs, an older one where I installed MacTex-2018 and a newer one where I installed  Mac Tex 2021. MacTex  works superbly in both cases.

My older laptop died and I got a new MacAir and  I have installed  MacTex2022. The result is  complete chaos. I have not experienced any of these problems  with any of the previous incarnations of MacTex and I have been using this soft for more than 15 years.

There are too many issues to list them all, but here is a sample.

The 2022 version has problems processing   files using the gsm-l package (created by  the American Math Soc for authors). It cannot  find this package apparently.I have no clue where to place  this package. I did not have to do anything special when using  version  < 2022. If I change the option gsm-l to a world scientific  .cls  option Things work fine.

I use  the packages  pb-diagram, pb-lams, lamsarrow to generate diagrams.  On some of my files they work. On most they do  not. I have the  lams fonts, placed  them in the Library directory as usual  but  it does not help because, sometimes  MacTex  cannot find them. On other occasions  I do not have thises issues.

The packages  graphicx and epstopf  also  work erratically.  That is, they work in some files, but on some other files  they cannot seem to locate   the .eps files.  I have included in my texts jpg and png files.    Same type of issue here.  Works on some files   fail on other.

I have not experienced any of the above issues using earlier versions  of Mac Tex. I work in the cloud (Dropbox)  so I have not changed  the structure of the directories containing the tex files I am working on.

Admittedly, my computer skills are limited, but I have  installed MacTex on about a dozen of Macs over the years and everything worked like I charm.  I have followed closely the installation instructions and I now have in my laptop a "beast" whose behavior does not display any obvious pattern.

I currently have Monterrey 12.3.1,   the same operating system on which MacTex 2021 on my other laptop works well.

I am out of ideas  and I would appreciate any suggestions you might have. Thanks!

**Update** The mystery deepens. In my frustration I  have installed MikTex  for Mac I did the following experiment.

I ran a Tex file using TexShop/MacTex  and I encountered   various problems. The process ended with a Fatal Error message.  Then I processed  the same TeX file using  miktex-texwork. Things worked well.  I tried TexShop again on the file. It worked like a charm. No more problems.

Did the same think with other TeX files and  I observed the same thing. TexShop works well only after I  first process the Tex file using miktex.

Including log files here seems pointless. There are too many types of errors that vary from  file to file  to discern a pattern.   I have my own TeX template  so they all have the same preamble.

**Final update** It is about Dropbox.  Starting with Monterrey upgrade Dropbox is not working properly. This affects the behavior of  MacTex2022  as well if  you try to work in the cloud. The earlier versions of MacTex do not seem to be affected by this.

Comment: start with *one* of the issues and describe it correctly: make a small example and show it together with the log-file  so that we can see the exact and full error message.

Comment: Where did you put the package before? That hasn't changed between previous versions and the 2022 version. If you put the file(s) in texmf-local you need to run `sudo -H mktexlsr` and give your admin password when requested. When you say you placed them in the `Library` folder what do you mean?

Comment: I am including a log file. It is a book  500 pages long. The output pdf  now is only 4 pages long

Comment: I have a  file (book) in two  style versions. One that uses a World Scientific style package  and one that uses the gsm-l package. The World Scientific  version works like a charm. and produces  a 500 page output.The gsl-m version stops  at the first  include graphics command. The epstopdf  is the problem. The pdf output is 4 pages. I cannot include the log file because it is too long.

Comment: try to remove epstopdf from your file. The conversion call is now in-built. Remove also pdfsync.sty, that is obsolete since many year.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I will try this.  However I have epstopdf  in both versions I mentioned above.  Everything is fine when using Wolrd Scientific class but everything goes wrong when I use ams style files.

Comment: Well I wrote you should provide a small example.  Then someone could test.

Comment: I removed the epstopdf and pdfsync  Stll not working. Everything works fine with MacTex 2021.

Comment: well the first error is with the graphic. So it should be trivial to  create a small failing example. Then would we no longer would have to guess what you do.

Comment: Here is what troubles me. Everything works wellwhen I use a World Scientfic  template: graphics, diagrams,  everything. If I use the same text with an amsbook template  then all sorts of problems appear.

Comment: Sigh... having both MikTeX and TeX Live (installed by MacTeX can certainly lead to problems. We really need you to help folks here figure out what is going on by providing an example that fails that we can work with.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MikTeX, which I wouldn't recommend for a Mac. I'm using TL 2022 with Monterey and Dropbox without incident. Dropbox now runs with Files on Demand all the time, and it's likely that existing `.aux` or `.sty` files in user folders will be present but appear as having no content, which can lead to errors on existing documents. This can also affect your local `texmf` if you have it symbolically linked to a Dropbox folder. For `.aux` files, you can just delete them and recompile. For local `.sty` and `.cls` files, just reopen the file first then recompile.

Comment: ...con't For a local `texmf` folder symbolically linked to a Dropbox folder, it's best to set that folder to be "Always available offline", which will stop Files on Demand from leaving files in the cloud. To do this, navigate to the folder in the Finder and then right-click/control-click on the folder icon. There will be Dropbox items there, choose the "Make available offline" item.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks! I will do this  and let you know what happens.

Comment: @AlanMunn   I've made my  folders   available offline and so far everything seems to be working without a hitch.  Thanks you very much.

Comment: Great! I’ll turn my comments into an answer then.

Comment: @AlanMunn Please do and I'll  award it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comments, I've managed to reconstruct the basic problem here, which relates to changes in the MacOS as of Monterey (OS 12) and apps like Dropbox and OneDrive.

As of MacOS 12, there are changes in the way that cloud based files are stored. Dropbox and OneDrive (and presumably other cloud sync solutions) now default to "Files on Demand" mode, which means that files that are not actively being used will remain on the server, and only get downloaded when opened. Effectively this means that although the files appear in the Finder as a kind of stub, they have no actual content.  This is a problem that Dropbox and OneDrive are aware of, but have not yet successfully fixed. It is hoped that they will and the solutions given below will no longer be necessary.

### Problems with (older) local files

When you try to compile a file which requires one of the "cloud only" files, the file will not be flagged as missing, (since it does exist), but it will effectively load no content. [Thanks to Phelype Oleinik for discussion of of how packages are loaded].

This will lead to errors in the following circumstances (probably a non-exhaustive list):

- existing `.aux` files that are supposed to be read during compilation
- files that are inserted into your main document with `\input` or `\include`
- local (to the source document folder) classes or packages

If any of these files are "cloud only" the code they contain will not exist, and any macros they define will then give rise to "Undefined control sequence errors". Such errors can be very misleading, since you would assume that the files are all there, especially on existing documents that used to compile without errors before.

### Problems with a `texmf` folder on Dropbox

Further problems can arise if you have your local `texmf` folder linked to a Dropbox folder as described here:

- [Centralised .bib file on Mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337952/2693)

If you do have this setup, then many of your locally installed packages and classes will have a "cloud only" status, and so will give rise to errors if you try to load them.

### Solutions

Depending on the situation, you can solve the problems in either a specific or general way.

#### Individual folder solution

For `.aux` files, simply deleting them before recompiling an old document should be sufficient.

For local `\input` or `\included` files or local to the source document folder packages or classes, simply opening these files first in your editor will download them and they will be usable again.

#### General solution

For a `texmf` folder linked to Dropbox, the solutions above are impractical. In this case a better long term solution is to make sure that the linked Dropbox folder is set to be "Make files available offline". This will stop the "cloud only" status from applying to that folder. Since the status applies recursively to all containing files and folders, you just need to set that status for the top level folder.  To do this, right-click (or control-click) on the Finder icon for the folder, and there will be a set of Dropbox menu items. Choose the "Make available offline" item.

Of course this solution will work for any individual folders, and since `.tex` files usually aren't large, it's probably fine to use it for an folder containing `.tex` files. But in practice, I don't think it's necessary for most situations, since the individual folder solutions are adequate.

There's also a global Dropbox setting to turn off Files on Demand, but this seems like a non-optimal solution, since Files on Demand is generally a useful space saver.